# Constants in function instead in separate file

Tags: python, function, methods, config, constants

I am writing because I am confused.
Generally I always place constants in separate file, which I import into main, executive file.
E.g NAME = private in conf.py and I import conf.py into executive file.
But I have such a situation that I need constants instead of hardcoding, but constants are created on the basis of input data.
E.g NAME = inputStr[0:4], where inputStr is an external input taken to the main function in executive file.
For this reason, I just can't place this constant into separate file because inputStr is not known for this file.
I hope I made the situation clear.
For this reason, may I put the constant into main function?
 I

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do:

main file(main.py):

`from file import *
//do whatever you want
print(name)
print(name[0:2])`

import file(file.py)

```
name = str(input("write somthing\n"))
```

run main file and you will be asked for the input and the code will continue like normal.

Comment: `from file import *` bad practice in general

Comment: I am not sure if I get it. My input is "input" as a parameter while running scrypt in cmd, but I think it is not so important. I just don't want to use name[0:2] but newName = name[0:2] in cfg file to use newName in main.py file and I am sure it will not work in this way.